# Sharepoint Access Denied RunWithElevatedPrivileges for SPFolder

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have the Access Denied error when I try to open a SPFolder although I run the code in `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`. I find several post on this topic and the solution that I found was:

- Don't use `SPContext.Current`
- Instantiate al SPObject inside the `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`
- Set to false `SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException`

Nothing works for me. Follow my code, the error occurs at:

```
SPFolder DocumentLibrary = web.Folders[Library];
```

My code:

```
bool originalCatchValue = SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException;
SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException = false;

try
{
    string[] ArrayId = Request["arrayId"].ToString().Split('|');
    string company = Request["company"].ToString();
    string NewSPContext = company == "XXX" ? siteCollectionUrl.Replace("XXX", "") : siteCollectionUrl + "XXX";
    SPUserToken userToken = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.UserToken;
    foreach (string id in ArrayId)
    {
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            SPSite oSite = new SPSite(siteCollectionUrl, userToken);
            SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb();
            SPFile itemFile = FindListByName(oWeb, Library).GetItemById(int.Parse(id)).File;
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(NewSPContext, userToken))
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                var test = web.CurrentUser;
                web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPFolder DocumentLibrary = web.Folders[Library];
                DocumentLibrary.Files.Add(itemFile.Item.Name, itemFile.OpenBinary(), itemFile.Properties, true);
                DocumentLibrary.Update();
            }
        });
    }
    Response.Write("OK");
}
finally
{
    SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException = originalCatchValue;
}
```

Comment: Please don't change title to "Solved". If some answer has fixed the problem, mark it as answer and upvote, to show appreciation and indicate (to others who come across similar issue) that it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you provide a user token to the constructor of the SPSite class, the created instance will run in the context of the specified user. Meaning, in your case, every operation you perform on the oSite object will be executed as if it's being called by the CurrentUser.

Just drop the user token parameter from the line where you instantiate the SPSite object and you should be good to go since your code elevates the privileges.

Having said that, there are multiple problems with your code. To say the least, it is very inefficient and it wouldn't pass a code review. Here are a few tips for you:

- Avoid recursive calls to the RunWithElevatedPrivileges function, it is an extremely expensive function.
- Try to reuse SPSite and SPWeb objects once you instantiate them instead of recreating them recursively in a loop. They are really expensive to construct.
- You must dispose all the instances of SPSite and SPWeb objects, otherwise you will end up with memory leaks that will deteriorate the application performance over time and most probably result in a crash in the end.

Comment: Thank you Serkan. I know that the code is not good. It is taken in the middle of my experiment to fix the problem. Said that, in this code I'm trying to copy a document from one site to another. I open the site with the current token becose I want to have the current user as creator of the copied document without give the right to the user on the second site. It is possible?

Comment: As long as the current user has sufficient access rights to the both locations then your code would just work fine even without elevating the execution context. If that's not the case, then after uploading the file to the target site, within the same function call, you could update the newly created document's Created By field with the name of the current user. This is something commonly done by migration tools to preserve original metadata of documents. So, it's a proven solution...